# C program not reading from file

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I'm new to C and filehandling and I am trying to print the contents of a file. I am using Code::Blocks if that matters. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("filename.txt", "rt");

    while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF){
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, and what's the problem?

Comment: `if (f==NULL) ... // error handling`

Comment: Assigning the result of `fgetc` to a `char` is wrong. `EOF` is not a `char`.

Comment: Please change `char c;` to `int c;` because that is the type returned by `fgetc()`. The value `EOF` must be distinguishable from the data value `0xFF`. It's still perfectly acceptable to use `printf("%c", c);` because a `char` used as an argument for `printf` is promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @flarp first, check the return value from `fopen` - you did not say what the problem is,

Comment: @WeatherVane how do I check the return value from fopen? I'm starting to think it has something to do with my IDE(code::blocks) not being able to locate it or something. And the problem is simply that nothing is being printed.

Comment: the posted code compiles/links just fine on my ubuntu linux 14.04 OS.  However the code fails to check for errors and fgetc() returns an 'int', not a 'char' and EOF is an 'int', so the posted code will never properly terminate

Comment: here is how to check for an error from `fopen()`.    Note: fopen() returns a NULL when it fails.   `if( NULL == (f = fopen("filename.txt, "rt"))) { // then fopen failed  perror( "fopen for filename.txt failed"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Note: `perror()` prints to stderr with the enclosed text plus the the system message that is selected by `errno`.

Comment: Why is the header file `ctype.h` being #include'd?  None of its' features are being used in the posted code.   Similarly, why is `string.h` being #include'd?  None of its' features are being used in the code.

Comment: this question fails to state what is going wrong with the posted code.  That makes it an invalid question.  Please edit the question to include the missing information.

Comment: @flarp "how do I check the return value from fopen?" I already posted that in the second comment.

Comment: try `printf("%c", c);fflush(stdout);`

Answer (score 0):

A quick note on *undefined behaviour*: If we were to suggest that it crashes, then we would be defining it to crash... We can't do that, because it's *undefined*. All we can say is that undefined behaviour is non-portable, probably undesirable and certainly to be avoided.

---

According to [the `fopen` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html), there are six standard modes for opening a file, and `"rt"` is not one of them.

I've quoted the section that lists these six standard modes. Notice the emphasis (mine), stating that the behaviour is undefined if you select something other than one of those standard modes.

> The mode argument points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file shall be opened in the indicated mode. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**
>
> `r` or `rb`
>
> ```
> Open file for reading.
> ```
>
> `w` or `wb`
>
> ```
> Truncate to zero length or create file for writing.
> ```
>
> `a` or `ab`
>
> ```
> Append; open or create file for writing at end-of-file.
> ```
>
> `r+` or `rb+` or `r+b`
>
> ```
> Open file for update (reading and writing).
> ```
>
> `w+` or `wb+` or `w+b`
>
> ```
> Truncate to zero length or create file for update.
> ```
>
> `a+` or `ab+` or `a+b`
>
> ```
> Append; open or create file for update, writing at end-of-file.
> ```

---

Okay, so with that in mind, you probably intended to use the `"r"` mode. Following `fopen`, you need to ensure the file opened successfully, as other people have mentioned in the comments. There are many errors that can occur, as I'm sure you can deduce... Your error handling should probably look something like this:

```
f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    puts("Error opening filename.txt");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

Others have also remarked on the return type of `fgetc`; it doesn't return a *`char`*. It returns an **`int`**, and for good reason. Most of the time it will successfully return one of (typically) 256 character values, as a *positive* `unsigned char` value converted to an `int`. Occasionally, however, you'll get a **negative** `int` value, `EOF`. That's an `int` value, not a character value. **The only character values `fgetc` returns are positive.**

So you should also perform error handling for `fgetc`, like so:

```
int c = getchar();
if (c == EOF) {
    return 0;
}
```